# Where is BepiColombo?

Tags: probe, bepicolombo

BepiColombo is a probe that was sent towards Mercury in October 2018. [It will flyby Earth in April 2020](http://www.esa.int/Science_Exploration/Space_Science/BepiColombo/BepiColombo_factsheet), but I would like to know where it is in the meantime. Is there a website that shows where in the Solar system BepiColombo currently is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes! Visit [this](https://www.cosmos.esa.int/web/bepicolombo) webpage.

It has interactive 3D tools, developed by the SGS team, shows the spacecraft attitude and where the European Space Agency's BepiColombo spacecraft is on any given day from launch in October 2018 to just beyond the end of its cruise phase end on November 2025 to reach Mercury planet. You can watch the entire journey play through or get the spacecraft’s current position. The information returned tells you how far Bepi Colombo (red track) is from the Sun, Mercury, Venus and Earth and the accumulated distance on its journey.

Here's how it looks:

[image]

You may select the specific events or slide to any date within the mission period. There are a bunch of information*.

[image]

Recommended browsers: Chrome & FireFox. *But it works in Microsoft Edge*

Bonus: You can know the Mission Status from the toolbar on the top right portion of the same page. There's a countdown for the next event too.

---

*But note that distances are based on the best values available at the time of preparing this tool and with respect to the center of the planets, but you should be aware that **this is not a scientific tool**. Note that the proportions and appearances of the planets and BepiColombo are not true representations, and no indication is given about the planet rotations.